# Read csv files via spark with changing column order

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to define a schema to read csv files via spark, where the column order changes between files

I.e. first file

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
2,3,4
```

second file

```
B,C,A
1,2,3
2,3,4
```

```
fSchema = StructType([
    StructField("A", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("B", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("C", IntegerType(), True)
])
```

spark.read.format('csv').option("header", "true").schema(fSchema).load('file1.csv')
returns

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |

```
spark.read.format('csv').option("header", "true").schema(fSchema).load('file2.csv')
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |

when I was expecting for the header column order to be understood due to the schema definition and re-order the data columns

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: Are you sing python or scala ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you apply a schema to a CSV it will use the order of columns and not the actual column names, if you want to match the column names you can use the below function:

```
def apply_schema_to_dataframe(df, schema):
    for field in schema.fields:
        df = df.withColumn(field.name, col(field.name).cast(field.dataType))
    return df
```

Here's how to use it:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)], ["A", "B", "C"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)], ["B", "C", "A"])

fSchema = StructType([
    StructField("A", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("B", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("C", IntegerType(), True)
])

apply_schema_to_dataframe(df1, fSchema).show()
apply_schema_to_dataframe(df2, fSchema).show()
```

The result is:

```
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+
|  B|  C|  A|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `enforceSchema` to false should solve your problem.

```
spark.read.format('csv')
.option("header","true")
.option("enforceSchema", "false")
.schema(fSchema)
.load('file2.csv')
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option

They mention that setting `enforceSchema` to true is generally recommended.
It is also worth mentioning that if you use `spark.read.csv(..)` the `enforceSchema` option you set will be ignored and default to True.